# Symfony 3.4 - cannot load field value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 3.4.47 w/ MySQL 8 and getting a field value wasn't a big thing until today.

I've created a migration file to add a new field to an existing entity:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE plano ADD cliente_apelido VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL');
```

And I've added the field 'cliente_apelido', getter and setter to the 'Plano.php' model:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cliente_apelido", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
 */
private $clienteapelido;

/**
 * @param string $clienteapelido
 */
public function setClienteapelido(string $clienteapelido): void
{
    $this->clienteapelido = $clienteapelido;
}

/**
 * Get clienteapelido.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getClienteapelido()
{
    return $this->clienteapelido;
}
```

It turns that, when I'm trying to use the getClienteapelido() getter, it returns an empty string and I don't have a clue of what's going wrong:

```
$plano = $this->doctrine->getRepository('PlanoBundle:Plano')->find(99); // 99 is just an example of a valid row of 'plano' entity

if ($plano) {
    $this->logger->critical("Found 'plano' id=" . $plano->getCodplano());
    // This prints to the log file:
    // [2021-09-13 09:36:31] app.CRITICAL: Found 'plano' id=99

    $this->logger->critical("apelido=[" . $plano->getClienteapelido() . "]");
    // This prints to the log file:
    // [2021-09-13 09:36:31] app.CRITICAL: apelido=[]
}
```

**Even worse:** The code above **is working in DEV environment** but does not work in production.
I know it sounds obviously like an environment issue, but i don't know where to look for.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: ** The problem was that I had some files/folders with wrong permissions on Symfony's cache folder, which made my deploy unable to clean it and that bizarre behavior was the consequence.

Comment: Did you check if the value was stored correctly in the database? Did you check if your app/database config is correct, especially around encoding? By default DoctrineBundle expects MySQL to use `utf8mb4` and if you call `APP_ENV=prod bin/console debug:config doctrine` you should see something to that effect

Comment: @dbrumann I'm almost sure its a cache problem. I've find out that cache:clear is not cleaning the app cache for some reason.
As it's a production env, I'll wait for the most appropriate time to manually remove my cache folder and then I'll update here.

Comment: @dbrumann the problem was actually wrong permission on cache files, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had some files/folders with wrong permissions on Symfony's cache folder, wich made my deploy unable to clean it and that bizarre behavior was the consequence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).